# What query will work for this sub-type / super-type relationship?

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is the situation. I have 3 tables, one super type, and two sub types, with a relationship between the sub types:

```
|----------------|    |-------------------| |-------------------|
|      Post      |    |     Top_Level     | |      Comment      |   
|----------------|    |-------------------| |-------------------|   
| PK | ID        |    | PK, FK | Post_ID  | | PK, FK | Post_ID  |   
|    | DATE      |    |        | Title    | |     FK | TopLv_ID |   
|    | Text      |    |-------------------| |-------------------|   
|----------------|
```

Each post, either comment or top_lev, is unique, but the entities share some attributes. So, comment and top_lev are sub types of post. That is one portion. Additionally, comments are associated with a top_lev post. This ER diagram illustrates this: http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/9327/sampleer.png

What I am looking for is a list of Top_Level posts ordered by activity on that top_level post, either creation of the top_level post, or a comment on that post.

For example, assume we have the following data:

```
|------------------------|    |------------------|    |--------------------|
|      Post              |    |     Top_Level    |    |       Comment      |
|------------------------|    |------------------|    |--------------------|
| ID |    DATE    | Text |    | Post_ID  | Title |    | Post_ID  |TopLv_ID |
|----|------------|------|    |----------|-------|    |----------|---------|
|  1 | 13/03/2008 | shy  |    |     1    |  XYZ  |    |     2    |    1    |
|  2 | 14/03/2008 | mrj  |    |     3    |  ABC  |    |     4    |    1    |
|  3 | 15/03/2008 | quw  |    |     7    |  NMO  |    |     5    |    3    |
|  4 | 16/03/2008 | ksi  |    |------------------|    |     6    |    1    |
|  5 | 17/03/2008 | kso  |                            |--------------------|
|  6 | 18/03/2008 | aoo  |                            
|  7 | 19/03/2008 | all  |                            
|------------------------|     

|--------------------------------|
|            RESULT              |
|--------------------------------|
| ID |    DATE    | Title | Text |
|----|------------|-------|------|
|  7 | 19/03/2008 |  123  | all  |
|  1 | 13/03/2008 |  ABC  | shy  |
|  3 | 15/03/2008 |  XYZ  | quw  |
|--------------------------------|
```

Can this be done with a single select statement? If so, how?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Since there is only one date column in the question (and that's on SUPER), what do you mean by "ordered by the date of the last occurrence of either a SUB1, or a SUB2 that is tied to that SUB1"?

Comment: I added a more real-world example. It isn't quite right because this isn't how you would set up such a circumstance, but it's close.

Comment: You have Posts, Top_Level (which I don't recognize), and Comment. What inherits from what? Something with "Date" and "Text" isn't a subclass of something with "Title", or vice versa, and the other looks like a junction table.

Comment: If you think of it like classes, instances of Top_Level are also instances of Post. Likewise, instances of Comment are also instances of Post. So, both Top_Level and Comment implicitly have Date and Text attributes, in addition to their specific ones. This is basic entity inheritance.

Comment: The situation is similar to a blog, with top_level posts, and comments on those. Both are a kind of post, but comments cannot have a title.

Comment: Your result set doesn't make sense to me.  The title 123 should be NMO; that's clearly a simple typo.  Are you trying to order the data by a column that you aren't selecting - or a value you aren't selecting?  Because the details you show are simply the details for the top-level post.

Comment: Why aren't you asking for the date of the last relevant posting (as well as, or instead of, the date of the top level posting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this query and it gives the output you describe:

```
SELECT pt.id, pt.`date`, t.title, pt.`text`
FROM Top_Level t INNER JOIN Post pt ON (t.post_id = pt.id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (Comment c INNER JOIN Post pc ON (c.post_id = pc.id))
   ON (c.toplv_id = t.post_id)
GROUP BY pt.id
ORDER BY MAX(GREATEST(pt.`date`, pc.`date`)) ASC;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+-------+------+
| id | date       | title | text |
+----+------------+-------+------+
|  7 | 2008-03-19 | NMO   | all  | 
|  1 | 2008-03-13 | XYZ   | shy  | 
|  3 | 2008-03-15 | ABC   | quw  | 
+----+------------+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You've perhaps unintentionally pretty thoroughly obfuscated your question, making it very difficult to understand and answer (at least for those of us with small brains.) Could you possibly restate it with reasonable table and field names, and a more complete description of indexes?

---

EDIT:

Are you possibly describing a situation where products are sold, and also sometimes the same products can be included as components in other products recursively? If so, there are more conventional successful ways to model the situation.

Comment: I have made the tables a bit more real. The example is still quite contrived, but is at least more comprehensible. Does that help?

Comment: What's the difference between an item, a product, and a component? And your example simply shows IDs for the 3 products, with their dates from the first table. What effect did the other two tables have, and why?

Comment: And the earliest buy_date in the list is 13-03-2008, for Product 1, but it's second in the list.

Comment: The example now should be much more comprehensible...it should work similarly to the SO front page.

Answer (score 0):

That should definitely be possible, as long as "date of the last occurrence" is represented in a column of Sub1 and Sub2.  Note that the code I'm listing is mostly pseudocode... you'll have to fill in the blanks according to your flavor of dbms.

To limit your result-set to only the columns in SUPER and SUB1 (with no dupes):

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub1.*, super.*
```

(obviously, you should try to avoid SELECT *... pick which columns you actually need)

You FROM clause would look something like:

```
FROM super INNER JOIN sub1 ON super_id
    LEFT JOIN sub2 ON super_id AND sub1_id
```

And ORDER BY would use the COALESCE function (if your dbms supports it) to figure out which column to sort by (COALESCE chooses the first non-null value in the argument list):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(sub2.dateColumn, sub1.dateColumn)
```

Alternatively, if you don't have COALESCE available but you do have an ISNULL function available, you can chain ISNULLs:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(firstDateColumn, ISNULL(secondDateColumn, thirdDateColumn))
```

Comment: Using MySQL, "SELECT DISTINCT sub1.*, super.* FROM super INNER JOIN sub1 ON sub1.super_id LEFT JOIN sub2 ON sub2.super_id AND sub2.sub1_id" gives each sub1 for each super, giving NxM rows rather than just M.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't suggest or hint that the schema could be re-designed, so perhaps my asking this question isn't the best use of your time and mine, but: do your tables **have** to be designed this way? Is this application already in production use?

What triggered this thought in my head was your statement:

> All events happen at a date, but edits must be associated with the
>   original creation event

I suspect that this is the rationale for having sub2 include a FK to sub1. But this feels to me like a denormalization (in relational terms) or a violation  of the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle (in Agile terms.) In either case, it may make your life more complicated than it needs to be.

My advice (worth what you're paying for it) would be to remove the FK to sub1. In its place, you can either 1) include a SELECT on the creation event for the page, as part of the query, or 2) Move the creation date into the page table. (Which of these options you take depends on how much additional complexity exists in the schema; I'd usually prefer #1 over #2.)

I would think that this would simplify your updates as well as your queries. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have updated the question to be a bit more clear. In my case, there is a clear supertype with 2 subtypes sort of relationship, but there is also a relationship between the two subtypes. The schema is NOT set, but since there truly is such a super/sub type relationship, this is the most "normal".

Comment: Your discussion of supertypes, subtypes, and relationships is not one I normally encounter in the context of discussing the normalization of a relational database. Are you confusing your conceptual frameworks?

Comment: The reason for having sub/super-type tables is to normalize. Identifying these relationships is the core of normalization. Otherwise, one lump table, with massive data replication, would suffice. However, a more normal DB is desired in this case.

Comment: Please provide some other kind of guidance -- an entity relationship diagram, perhaps. I cannot make heads or tails of what you're trying to achieve, and from what I gather, neither can anyone else.

Comment: Hint: I'd expect that all Comments having the same FK to Top_Level, would also have the same FK to Post; and that the shared Top_Level would also have the same FK to Post. Please help me understand why that's not the case.

Comment: Each post, either comment or top_lev, is unique. So, comment and top_lev are sub types of post. That is one portion. Additionally, comments are associated with a top_lev post. This ER diagram illustrates this: http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/9327/sampleer.png

Comment: Your example shows a Comment where Post_ID=7 and TopLv_ID=3, and a Top_Level entry where  PostID=7. Either these are errors in the example, or the relationships are still very unclear.